# Хранение изображений публичных и скрытых - организация

Tags: php, изображения, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Необходимо реализовать хранение большого количества фото.
Каждый пользователь может загружать большие объемы картинок, при этом ограничений на размер  и количество нет. (есть ряд требований к фото, так что хлама не будет)

Но при этом нужно сделать такую структуру, чтобы некоторые изображения были недоступны всем подряд и имели пути, которые нельзя найти.

Например если структура
/upload/images/id-юзера/день-месяц-год/размер-изображения/image.jpg
То определить путь будет не сложно. Да и не уверен я в организации такой структуры каталогов.

Можно название директории генерировать случайно, с каким-то ключом.
Но остается вопрос хранения данных в БД.
Если структура каталогов будет фиксированной, то можно в БД хранить уникальный кей каталога и название изображения.
т.е. id | img_key | img_name
Тогда /upload/images/id-юзера/img_key/images_size/img_name

есть у кого опыт в реализации чего-то подобного? Был бы рад советам.

Comment: А зачем требование о том, что пути "нельзя найти"? Просто не отдавайте пользователю картинку, если на неё прав нету.

Comment: Я как раз пока не понял как лучше делать разграничение прав в таком случае.
К примеру один пользователь запретил просмотр другому, а третьему разрешил.

При этом не определился со структурой директорий хранения.
ниже приводил пример с 500px, но не понял как там реализовано, что в случае закрытости файла, отдается xml

Comment: @drop_off: Ну так для каждой картинки храните список тех, кому доступ разрешён (и флаг "доступна всем"). Или картинки с одинаковыми правами храните в одном каталоге, и назначайте права каждому каталогу. Или если есть hard links в ОС на сервере, храните по каталогу для каждого пользователя (`/ownerid/visitorid/`), и соединяйте одинаковые картинки hardlink'ом. Или храните все картинки где угодно, а права и путь к ним в базе.

Comment: @VladD , для меня сложно пока это все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока ехал в метро, прикинул следующее:

- вынести фото на отдельную площадку
- отдавать файлы с помощью `php` - не вариант.
- смастерить какой-нибудь файловый сервак на node.js - вариант

Вариант еще тем, что можно с успехом привинтить какую-нибудь БД, дабы получить полный контроль за файлами и папками. Тут уже и блочить доступ можно, либо 404, либо что угодно.

в БД какую-нибудь табличку с ключом по хешу, генерируемому по строке запроса, либо в начало запроса вставлять тот-же ключ, который поможет отсеять большинство левых запросов (соответственно ключ потом можно с чем угодно сверить).

---

Еще есть частная версия хранилища на php и htaccess:

> /user/album/.*

Если альбом открытый, то просмотр без препятствий.
Если альбом закрытый и разрешен для просмотра только владельцу, то в альбоме создаем .htaccess файл с содержанием:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} login=user[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} password=e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e[NC]
RewriteRule .* /404.html [NC,L]
```

Т.е. чтобы закрыть альбом, добавляем файл, добавляем какие-то определенные куки, по которым должна происходить идентификация. Всё подходит - показываем. Нет? - редиректим.

Comment: через htaccess не вариант. фото будет закрыто не полностью для всех, а для большинства. типа фото для друзей и т.д...

Мне интересно как организовывать структуру каталогов.
Получается два типа изображений
1 - открытый - имеют доступ все
2 - закрытый - доступ регулируется правами

И как быть с правами и директорией хранения в данном случае?.
С node.js - я на Вы. Пока разбираюсь только php, mysql...

Comment: Посмотрел сейчас как на крупных серсисах
Например 500px
http://pcdn.500px.net/1309557/6309cb4b9607498ce256027407c732ee5e10a722/11.jpg
и
http://pcdn.500px.net/1309557/6309cb4b9607498ce256027407c732ee5e10a722/15.jpg

15.jpg - доступна
11.jpg - не доступна

При этом отдается вообще XML.

Comment: @dropoff я склоняюсь к самому простому варианту: добавить определенный токен папке/файлам.

Про крупные сервисы: у них там в заголовках явно видно: 
Server ECS (jfk/25E9)

Comment: прошу прощения, но можно немного подробнее на счет токена?

Server ECS (jfk/25E9) - это что?
Так же написано было, что сервер амазон.

Comment: @drop_off токен = ключ. 

Server ECS видимо какой-то файловый сервер, который стоит на амазоне.

Comment: Я понял, что имелся в виду ключ. я не понял как применять).

Кстати. Почему Вы пишете, что отдавать файл скриптом не вариант?

Comment: то что вы описали называется cdn

Comment: @eicto далеко нет.